# SqlDataAdapter with using keyword

Tags: c#, ado.net, dispose, using, sqldataadapter

Is this the following code healthy? Or I don't need to use the `using` keyword as the `SqlDataAdapter` will handle closing the connection?

```
public static DataSet Fetch(string sp, SqlParameter [] prm)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = sp;
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prm);

            using (SqlDataAdapter dta = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataSet dst = new DataSet();
                dta.Fill(dst);

                return dst;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

@MarkGravell I need a suggestions here, I am really looking to use `DataReader`, but I was looking all the time to use the `using` keyword to ensure closing the connections. Where with `DataReader` we can not use it because it will close the connection if we want to return the `DataReader` back to some method.
So do you think the following technique is fine with `DataReader` and the `using` keyword:

```
public static SqlDataReader Fetch(string sp, SqlParameter [] prm)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlConnection(ConStr).CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = sp;
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prm);
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

using (SqlDataReader dtrPrize = Sql.Fetch("SelectPrize", new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("id", id) }))
{
    dtrPrize.Read();

    Prize prize = new Prize();
    prize.id = (int)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("id")];
    prize.artitle = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("artitle")];
    prize.entitle = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("entitle")];
    prize.ardetail = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("ardetail")];
    prize.endetail = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("endetail")];
    prize.image = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("image")];
    prize.theme = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("theme")];
    prize.price = (int)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("price")];
    prize.audience = (int)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("audience")];
    prize.type = (byte)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("type")];
    prize.status = (byte)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("status")];
    prize.voucher = (string)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("voucher")];
    prize.supplierid = (int)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("supplierid")];
    prize.created = (DateTime)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("created")];
    prize.updated = (DateTime)dtrPrize[dtrPrize.GetOrdinal("updated")];

    return prize;
}
```

Comment: The code is fine. The `Connection` will be opened/closed implicitely in `DataAdapter.Fill`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Healthy-ish; personally I'd say the unhealthy bit is the bit where it makes use of `DataSet` and `DataAdapter`, but that is perhaps just my personal bias.

Yes, you should dispose the adapter etc here (which is what the `using` does for you, obviously).

As a trivial pointless tidy, you can stack the `using`s - just makes it a little less verbose:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
```

Comment: @MarkGravell Could you explaine, why the adapter should be disposed also? Is SqlConnection dispose not enought?

Comment: @voo Because it implements `IDisposable`, and we're done with it. That is reason enough. Anything beyond that is going into implementation details, which we should avoid. As a consumer, all it needs to come down to is: "does it implement `IDisposable`? am I done with it?"

Comment: @MarkGravell as you mentioned the DataAdapter and DataSet might be unhealthy, do you mean its better to use DataReader, map it to an object, close the connection and finally return the model object rather than returning the DataSet? Whats your recommendations over here?

Comment: @user2155873 I do indeed strongly lead towards a regular object model here (rather than DataSet). How you interact with that is up to you: there are a myriad of ORM tools available. Personally I use a lot of "dapper", but that might just be personal bias.

Answer (score 0):

It will be enough to leave just the first `using` (the one on the Connection) because disposing the connection will dispose everything you need disposed.

However, there is no harm disposing everything, just a bit more code.