# how to retrieve data from database into textbox and save the edited data from the same textbox to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

i m working on a web application that stores user information, i want to get the userdetails from the database into textboxes where i can make changes to the data and use a button to store the data from the same text boxes to the same table of the database.it is like updating/ editing user profile
 so far i am able to get the data into textboxes but i am unable to update the data. the page submits the data but there is no change in the data base

the  html & code i am using is:

```
<div id="pagebody" style="width: 80%; height: 120%; margin: auto;">
    <div id="personalinfodiv" class="try" align="center" style="background-color: white; width: 80%; border: 1px solid gray; margin: auto">
        <h3 align="center" >Personal information</h3>
        <table>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="fname"  runat="server" Text="First Name  :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>  <td><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox1"  ID="firstnametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="lname" runat="server" Text="Last Name  :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>  <td><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox1" ID="lastnametext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="gender" runat="server" Text="Gender  :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>  <td><asp:DropDownList cssClass="textbox1" ID="gendertext" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Gender" DataValueField="Gender"><asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="1"></asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="2"></asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Koshur %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Gender] FROM [userdetails] WHERE ([Username] = @Username)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Username" QueryStringField="user" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="dob" runat="server" Text="Date of Birth  :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>  <td><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox1" ID="dobtext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="Contactno" runat="server" Text="Contact No :" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="GrayText"></asp:Label></td>  <td><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox1" ID="contacttext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </td></tr>
        </table>
```

C# for data retrieval :

```
string CSs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Koshur"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CSs))
{
    string query = "select * from userdetails where Username='" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "';";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "userdetails");
    firstnametext.Text=ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Firstname"].ToString();
    lastnametext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Lastname"].ToString();
    dobtext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Dateofbirth"].ToString();
    contacttext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["ContactNO"].ToString();
}
```

c# to update the data into table and
i m using a stored procedure for this

```
protected void savecontinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Response.Redirect("test.aspx?q=" + firstnametext.Text +"&" + lastnametext.Text);
   string ct = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Koshur"].ConnectionString;
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ct))
   {
       SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("spupdateuserprofiledetails", con);
       cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       SqlParameter first = new SqlParameter("@Firstname", firstnametext.Text);
       SqlParameter last =new SqlParameter("@Lastname", lastnametext.Text);

       SqlParameter dobb=new SqlParameter("@Dateofbirth", dobtext.Text);
       SqlParameter connt=new SqlParameter("@ContactNo", contacttext.Text);
       SqlParameter userna = new SqlParameter("@Username", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString());

       cmnd.Parameters.Add(first);
       cmnd.Parameters.Add(last);
       cmnd.Parameters.Add(dobb);
       cmnd.Parameters.Add(connt);
       cmnd.Parameters.Add(userna);

       con.Open();
       cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
}
```

this is my stored procedure

```
create proc spupdateuserprofiledetails
@Firstname varchar(100),
@Lastname Varchar(100),
@Dateofbirth varchar(100),
@ContactNo varchar(100),
@Username varchar(100)
as
begin
update Userdetails
set Firstname=@Firstname,Lastname=@Lastname,Dateofbirth=@Dateofbirth,ContactNO=@ContactNo 
where Username=@Username

end
```

Comment: could you please also post your spupdateuserprofiledetails?

Comment: Possible SQL Injection attach in the SELECT query

Comment: In SQL Server, don't use the prefix "sp" for stored procs: the database engine looks for those in the system database first adding milliseconds to your processing time

Comment: If you have the full version of SQL Server, switch on Profiler (from tools) to see if the sp is being called

Comment: storedprocedure works fine, when i execute it in in sql server it updates the data, but in the webapplicatiton there is no updation,i get the previous data back

Comment: i posted the storedporecedure of my question aswell. can you lookup my query

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took quite a lot of time but finally I was able to get the answer. It was a just a lucky guess.

I was able to solve my problem by wrapping up data retrieval code:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    string CSs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Koshur"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CSs))
    {
        string query = "select * from userdetails where Username='" + 
            HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "';";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "userdetails");
        firstnametext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Firstname"].ToString();
        lastnametext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Lastname"].ToString();
        dobtext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["Dateofbirth"].ToString();
        contacttext.Text = ds.Tables["userdetails"].Rows[0]["ContactNO"].ToString();
    }
}
```

This worked fine. I am able to retrieve the data perfectly and also able to save it to the database using the same textboxes. that was my basic requirement. I DID NOT CHANGE ANY CODE FOR SAVING THE DATA INTO THE DATABASE (i.e the on save button event).

Comment: I removed the additional answer from your post. If you have a new question, please post a new question. If this post is not a true solution to your problem, don't post this as an answer and instead edit your original question.

Comment: You should "encapsulate" SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter in a using block; [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333522/sqldataadapter-with-using-keyword).

Comment: this is the answer for my problem, but i wanted to know what just happend with (!IsPostBack).i want an expert explanation. i mentioned it that it was a lucky guess. please answer. dont criticise

Comment: So, notice that the reason you didn't get this answer over a month ago is that you didn't show the context of  your data retrieval code. If you had shown that it was inside of Page_Load, or called from Page_Load, you would have received immediate answers about `if (!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: i know. it is my fault actually. i should have mentioned it earlier.. can you explain what is the role of     if (!IsPostBack)
on data storage into database? it is confusing because pageload event is usend only for data retrieval

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the way you add parameter for the `SqlCommand` collection. Or it might happen that the parameter value (`Username`) you pass to the stored procedure doesn't match with the database value you have specified in the condition. May be check the value of  both `@Username` and the value in the database for the `UserName` column doesn't contain any white spaces.

Try the below code and see if it helps. You can use `AddWithValue` which does the implicit conversion of types and it replaces the `SqlParameterCollection.Add` method.  Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999751/difference-between-parameters-add-and-parameters-addwithvalue) where you can study the different between the two.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ct))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmnd = new SqlCommand("spupdateuserprofiledetails", con))
   { 
      cmnd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      string userName  = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
      cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstnametext.Text));
      cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastnametext.Text));
      cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dateofbirth", dobtext.Text));
      cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNo", contacttext.Text));
      cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName));

      // Or If you are planning to use the `Add` method instead of the `AddWithValues` then make sure you explicitly specify the type of the parameter you pass to the stored procedure.
      // cmnd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstnametext.Text;
      // cmnd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastnametext.Text;
      // and so on

      con.Open();
      cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Comment: when i try to execute the sp in sql server it works fine.. the data is updated. but through the web page it dosent show any changes, also i have tried ADDWITHVALUE, it didnt work either. intitially i also thought that its not taking the username from "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString());"  i tried another method of finding wheather the data in textbox is realy updating or not for that i posted from the textbox to another page in its querystring, there also data is not changed..i have written the querystring code aswell in // section..

Comment: Please do not recommend using [AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).